# How to make OpenLayers.Popup draggable?

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, jquery

I've used jquery-ui draggable option as following but the moving popup can not be ended once dragging has started. Is there any another method to make OpenLayers.Popup draggable?

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble(
    "JInfo", // id
    jFeature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(), // lonlat
    new OpenLayers.Size(ISA.Size.POPUP_WIDTH,ISA.Size.POPUP_HEIGHT),
    html, // contentHTML
    null, // anchor
    true, // closeBox
    function(){  
        // closeBoxCallback
        jSelectControl.unselect(jFeature);
    }
);        
jFeature.popup = popup;    
map.addPopup(popup);    
$("#JInfo").draggable();
```

Answer (score 2):

An OL extension has been coded for that.

You will find a blog post relative to the draggable behavior and the extension implementation : http://aamirafridi.com/openlayers/openlayers-draggable-popups

With a link to the demo : http://jsbin.com/agopa3

The extension full code is available on the blog page. Hope it helps.